# Error occur after add a UDP server and client

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a program by using objective-c. Now I am going to add a UDP server and client into my project, before I add the file into xcode project, the project can be run successfully. But after I add another mainudp.m and upd.h and upd.m, the program cannot run and here is the error message, how to cope with this issue? Thanks

```
Ld /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Products/Debug/dd.app/Contents/MacOS/dd normal x86_64
    cd /Users/bacd/Desktop/de
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/bacd/Desktop/de/Bluewear\ OSX -filelist /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Intermediates/dd.build/Debug/dd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dd.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreAudio -framework Carbon -framework IOBluetooth -framework Cocoa -framework CoreServices -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Intermediates/dd.build/Debug/dd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dd_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Products/Debug/dd.app/Contents/MacOS/dd

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Intermediates/dd.build/Debug/dd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/bacd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dd-hggkyympepqrutcpbxxlwmtzcjkb/Build/Intermediates/dd.build/Debug/dd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mainudp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new file (`mainudp.m`) must define a `main()` function, which is the entry-point into the program.  You can only have one entry point and you already have one in your existing code.

You will either need to remove that new file or remove the `main()` function it contains and access any functionality it provides via your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your project you have dragged the whole 3rd party project, that's why there is two `main()` implementation one in your own project in `main.m` file and another in the third party project probably in `mainudp.m` file. That's why it is creating the issue. Try to drag drop only the useful classes not the whole project.